# Why am i getting null for calculating a total?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have the following Sale model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const SaleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  tickets: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Ticket',
      required: true,
    },
  ],
  total: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

const Sale = mongoose.model('Sale', SaleSchema);

module.exports = Sale;
```

i want to find all my sales and accumulate the total property. So i want to calculate the whole total made from all sales.

And this is my method:

```
//@desc      Get the total amount of all sales
//@method    GET
//@access    Private

exports.getTotalSales = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const sales = await Sale.find();

  if (!sales) {
    return next(new ErrorResponse(`No sales found`));
  }

  let total = 0;
  sales.forEach((sale) => {
    total += sale.total;
  });

  console.log(total);

  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    total,
  });
});
```

Till yesterday my method was working fine, but now i am getting in my response the following:

```
success: true,
total: null
```

I´ve console logged `total` and i get `NaN` but all of my sales have the total as number and not as a string or other type of data.

I didnt change anything to my method and the logic seems to be fine. Is there any reason why am i getting null to in my total?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer! Do you care to shortly leave a sentence on what caused the behavior in detail? What were the types of the misformed document? Was it a human error or how did it get in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me this looks like someone snuck a document in your collection, where the `total` attribute is anything different than a number. When trying query for the documents, mongoose try to parse this document to a number, but is not able to do so, resulting in `NaN`.

When trying to sum up the values, anything summed up with `NaN` results in `NaN`, which would show this exact behavior.

Maybe you can check your collection for any document, that doesn't follow your schema, e.g. having the `total` attribute set to anything different than a number. Your MongoDB collection would not care, so I guess this could definitely be the root cause here.